# Gaussian quadratures problems with precision and stability

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, approximate-integration

We have gaussian quadratures method:
$$
\int\limits^\infty_0 f(x) \,\mathrm{d}x \approx \sum\limits^n_i w_i f(x_i)
$$

I want to compute abscissas and the weights for various $n$ ( where $n$ will be users input) for lognormal distribution function.
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}x\sigma} \exp\left( -\frac{(\ln(x) - \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} \right)
$$

We all know that integrating over the $\mathbb{R}$ we will get $1$. This is my sanity check that gaussian quadratures works fine.

My questions are:

- Which Hermite, Legendre, Laguerre quadrature should I use for my
  case?
- Why do I get different precision for Laguerre (best choice approach as
  it approximates integral $[0, \infty)$)? (Peculiar: higher $n$ gives a
  worse result (checked through the sci.py library)) the same - not good result (in best case $0.99978$ or something close to this) I get from Legendre and as well it is not stable. I omit Hermite, as there are negative abscissas.
- Is it normal or I can get better "quality" result?
- I started to doubt that we can freely choose $n$. I think that as result is
  unstable (and as I often see - result does not improve with higher $n$) the method works only for some fixed $n$, not all $n$. Why is it unstable and how can I guarantee stability?

I fail to succeed to understand this method a bit reading at wiki and other sources. So as starting point I would like to know the whole idea with this:

- What does this line in Wiki mean:

> An $n$-point Gaussian quadrature rule, named after Carl Friedrich Gauss, is a quadrature rule constructed to yield an exact result for polynomials of degree $2n − 1$ or less by a suitable choice of the points $x_i$ and weights $w_i$ for $i \in \{1, \ldots, n \}$.

- Do we have in general better polynomials for particularly case of
  lognormal function? I do ask this because at book *Numerical recipes
  in C*, it is said that it is possible to choose for specific cases $w_i$
  and $x_i$ (i.e., abscissas and weights).

I have not studied numercial methods, therefore, if there is a golden book with preferably examples, I and probably other users would be grateful to know.

Comment: It is better if you break up your questions. As it stands, you are asking a lot of questions in a single post?

Comment: As for book recommendations, consider "Numerical Analysis, Sauer." If that is too basic, I can suggest more.

Comment: #1: You seem to have a basic misunderstanding of what the types of Gaussian quadrature are for. Gaussian quadrature is all about computing $\int f(x) w(x) dx$ for different intervals and different nonnegative weight functions $w$. To choose a type of Gaussian quadrature you need to know what interval you're using and hopefully something about the type of decay that your function demonstrates (so that hopefully most of the behavior of the integrand can be absorbed into the weight function). #2: your pdf for the lognormal distribution is wrong.

Comment: #3: Hermite integration will always be symmetric about $x=0$. You can delete the negative abscissas and get a Gaussian quadrature type that has no standard name, which could be used for integrating against the positive part of a normal distribution. #4: It is not really a surprise that you might have stability issues because you will be adding tiny numbers to O(1) numbers.  #5: Why not just compute the lognormal CDF using the normal CDF and a change of variable?

Comment: #6: Your question about the abscissas and nodes seems to reflect some misunderstanding of the point of Gaussian quadrature. The whole point is that you want to approximate $\int f(x) w(x) dx$ by a sum of the form $\sum_j w_j f(x_j)$ in such a way that you can take $f$ to be as high of a degree of a polynomial as possible while still getting exact integrations. It turns out that this degree is $2n-1$ where $n$ is the number of abscissae. In this case given an interval and a weight function, the Gaussian quadrature formula is *unique*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your question, "what does this line in Wiki mean"

> An $n$-point Gaussian quadrature rule, named after Carl Friedrich Gauss, is a quadrature rule constructed to yield an exact result for polynomials of degree $2n − 1$ or less by a suitable choice of the points $x_i$ and weights $w_i$ for $i \in \{1, \ldots, n \}$.

It means that the Gaussian quadrature(GQ) rule is exact for polynomials of degree $2n-1$ or less. In other words, if you integrate such a polynomial exactly and compare the result you get from GQ, there is no difference.
The error is zero. This is however not the case for higher degree polynomials or other functions. In a programming language that suits you, write a code
that does GQ. Consider a polynomial of degree $2n-1$ integrated from $a$ to $b$. Your result from the code should be exactly the same as what you integrate by hand. The take home message is that GQ is good since it can integrate things exactly to that degree. Other methods don't.

Comment: Dear @felasfa, thank you! do you know why integrating lognormal distribution is so bad in precision? I have seen other black box realisation of quadratures( I do not know which one but the resulting sum is precisely 1 unlike I have)

Comment: Can you please share as well more "deep into quadratures" book to read? The Sauer wrote in a clear, nice manner but too little about precision and similar issues.

Comment: @Jenya, I don't know much about integrating lognormal distribution. If Sauer is easy, consider "Introduction to numerical analysis, Hilderbrand". It is a good book of which I own a copy. Ch.8 covers GQ as well as other quadratures. Basic Gaussian quadrature is not too difficult to understand, for example consider these notes www.math.usm.edu/lambers/mat460/fall09/lecture31.pdf. best