# Integrating with Gaussian quadratures method. Precision and Stability

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, approximate-integration

We have gaussian quadratures method:
$$
\int^\infty_0 f(x) dx \approx \sum^n_iw_i f(x_i)
$$

I want to compute abscissas and the weights for various $n$ ( where $n$ will be users input) for lognormal distribution function.
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}x\sigma} e^{-\frac{(log(x) - \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$

Analytical integration over the $R$ gives $\int_R f = 1$. 
This is my sanity check that Gaussian quadratures works fine.

1. Why does higher $n$ gives worse result ? ( Is it some kind of over-fitting?)
2. Can I get the same precision for different $n$? ( I want my result be stable)

The best result I get is aprox. $0.99978$ (for $n \approx 20$ I get it from Laguerre quadrature method. )

I ask this because I saw black box realization of Gauss quadrature for lognormal function, where the sum of weigths multiplied by function of abscissas always give sum equal to 1 (for any $n$ I put inside).

---

I did ask question before:
[Gaussian quadratures problems with precision and stability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1961152/gaussian-quadratures-problems-with-precision-and-stability)

There I got a better understanding but still not clear picture what is wrong in what I am doing.

I also found that the error should be (for Legendre)
$$\frac{(b-a)^{2n+1} (n!)^4}{(2n+1) (2n!)^3} f^{(2n)} (\xi) , \quad \xi \in [a,b]$$
so I believe that black box is doing smth. different, as no visible error in sum of abscissas and weights is present.

3. Is it right? If yes, what shall I do to get similar effect as in the black box?

Also I have tried to split interval of integration into two parts: 
$$[0,a] -\text{integrate by Legendre, } [a,\infty) -\text{integrate by Laguerre, }$$
My result: $0.999992$ (21 points for each method,i.e. in total 41 distinct points) - which is obviously better than it was before but I still want to get maximum precision and stability possible.
I read a Davis, Rabinowitz book "Methods of numerical integration", which was the most rigorous about the topic and yet I understood something :), but it did not cover the precision, stability as I wanted.

There were propositions to use Stroud,Secrest method, Konrad Patterson, preassign abscissas but I do not know still how to do that in my case.

P.S. I do need to have as a solution 2 vectors: abscissas and weights that give me the sum of $\sum_i w_i f(\text{abscissas}_i)=1 $.

When I have obtained the $0.999992$ value, I used Legendre method for interval $[0,a]$ and for $[a,\infty)$ interval I have used Laguerre method. Of course, for Laguerre I plugged in the integral extra exponent
$$\int^\infty_a e^{-x}\underset{g(x)}{(e^x f(x))}dx \approx \sum^n_i w_i g(x_i)$$

I have been asked to do precisely Gaussian quadratures of lognormal as it gives $(x_i,w_i)$ that will be used for other analysis further.
Anyway, I myself can not understand how that black box works ( I do not know how it works, but in its description it says: plug mean, standard deviation and get 2 vectors of abscissas and weights), and I doubt myself if it is doing the same stuff as I have been asked.

That is why I ask questions (1)-(3), I want to understand what are the limits in precision, stability and if am I doing everything correct. I am computing that approximate integral, as black box gives 1.

I am sorry if I am not too precise ( if I can improve smth -please tell)

Comment: Gauss-Legendre integration is supposed to work on a bounded interval. Also, contrary to what you seem to believe, the weights and abscissas are not recomputed for each function $f$ to integrate. Where did you see this "black box" you mention? What makes you believe it uses gaussian integration?

Comment: Laguerre is intended for integrals with a factor of $\exp(-x)$ (or $x^\alpha \exp(-x)$ in the most general form); trying it on the Gaussian integral will not do you any favors.

Comment: Notice that we have Laguerre quadrature for integration against an exponential distribution and Hermite quadrature for integration against a normal distribution. This should show you a recurring theme: when you want to integrate against some fairly "standard" distribution, it is a good idea to not reduce it to some known Gaussian quadrature method, but to invent a new one for your own purpose. This will have a much better chance of numerically integrating to $1$.

Comment: Anyway, where did this "black box" come from? I doubt any standard tool for numerical integration of the lognormal distribution uses Gaussian quadrature. I would expect it to use a normcdf routine after changing variables.

Comment: What are you *really* trying to do? If you are trying to compute a CDF by integration for a common distribution, you'd better have a look at how software like [R](https://www.r-project.org/) do it. The documentation gives some hints: for computations with the lognormal distribution, it uses the normal distribution, and code from W. D. Cody.

Comment: Even with your "adjustment", Laguerre will behave poorly. You don't have to believe me; you can do a few experiments yourself and see if you can compute $\int_0^\infty \exp(-u^2)\mathrm du$ with it.

Comment: That'll break, too; Hermite is intended for the interval $(-\infty,\infty)$. In short, I am trying to dissuade you from using Laguerre or Hermite in this case as they are not appropriate.

Comment: Dear @J.M. Am I then right that I can not get a good result with quadratures? What then this method used for? Is it just for polynomials? Do you know any other way to obtain precise values of weights and the function's abscissas to get approximation of that integral in a good way?

Comment: Gaussian quadrature is useful when your integrand is fairly close to a polynomial times the weight function of interest. When using, say, Hermite integration to integrate the lognormal PDF, this is very much not the case, because the tail of the lognormal distribution is much fatter than the corresponding normal distribution. This gives you bad behavior, since you are integrating a function with superpolynomial growth at infinity against a normal distribution.

Comment: One way that Gaussian quadrature would be useful that is *related* to this problem is computing expected values of smooth functions under a given lognormal distribution. But in this case you would want to precompute the weights and abscissae for such a Gaussian quadrature. Doing so would wind up building the fact that the integral $\int 1 w(x) dx$ is $1$ into the method explicitly. (Note that in for example Hermite integration, the weights have $\sqrt{\pi}$ built into their definition.)

Comment: @Ian Could you please explain more in detail what you propose?

Comment: What I'm suggesting is not a way to directly integrate the lognormal pdf, so I don't think it is very relevant. For that problem I would recommend just using a standard normal distribution routine with a change of variable.

Comment: Note though that a perfectly good normal distribution routine is Hermite quadrature. It's not what is used in standard software but it works decently.